# Can anyone help me identify this uniform?

Tags: military, world-war-one, identification, uniform

Can anyone help me identify this uniform?

[image]

I have been looking into an ancestor named Frederick Collins who served in the Royal Garrison Artillery, in Ireland in 1898, South Africa 1900-1902 then St Helena until 1904. He was in 97th Company during this spell, leaving in 1904 but re-joining in 1906. Looks like he stayed in South Africa until the 97th was called to France in 1916, and he died serving in 81st siege Battery in France 1917. The picture is entitled 'Fred' and no other info. It has been passed through a few generations and landed with me recently. So I'm trying to see if this is actually *my* Fred in the image!

Comment: What do you already know about it? For example, where did you get the image? Do you know who it is? Which country?